# FTP Error 530 User cannot login

Tags: iis-7, ftp, windows-server-2008-web

I am trying to FTP to a new FTP site I setup with IIS 7.0 for the Windows Server Web (64-bit) edition. But I get the above error when I try to login to this site. But I can login to my other FTP sites.

Also, when I select this website from IIS Manager, the FTP section does not display in the middle section although it does display in Action panel. And I cannot successfully login to this FTP site either.

I have checked and I have Log on locally selected. I do not have allow only anonymous connections. I have Access this computer from the network selected.

I restarted my IIS and FTP services also.

The one different thing I noticed about this website in IIS different from the other site that has FTP working is that this one there are 3 virtual directories beneath the site. And that when I click on any one of these 3, then the FTP strip does appear in the center pane. Make sense?

How can I debug cause of this error? Any SW tools I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem.  Problem was I had two instances of IIS: 6 and 7.  I was modifying the wrong instance.